# error: ';' expected but double literal found

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and I am using typesafe activator to run the programs. I have my first program in the below path `<downloads>\typesafe-activator-1.3.7\activator-dist-1.3.7\simple scala project\scala-2.11\Simple_scala_project.scala`

Below is the program content

```
object Simple_scala_project {
    def main (args:String): Unit = 
        {   println("My first scala program") }
}
```

when I am running the below command in the command line I am getting the error

```
scala -cp <downloads>\typesafe-activator-1.3.7\activator-dist-1.3.7\simple scala project\scala-2.11 Simple_scala_project

:1: error: ';' expected but double literal found.
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: That's... Very strange. It doesn't even look like your running the correct source file. Is it possible that you made a copy of the file, and started editing the copy, and are trying to compile the original?

Comment: Put quotes (`"`) around that path, or, to avoid going insane, never use paths with spaces in them for programming stuff.

Comment: @Mat Oh, hehe. I didn't look at the path... I forgot about the pain that spaces in your path cause ;)

Comment: @JAtkin I haven't made the copy, I typed program my self in a new file

Comment: Thanks @mat for the quick look

Answer (score 0):

I noted a similar error when I inadvertently placed a line including "**sbt.version=1.3.13**" (in my case) in the wrong file.  I realize now that it should have gone into a folder insider my overall project folder called "project", inside a file called "build.properties" (instead of in "build.sbt").

The take-away from this is that I don't think you experienced a compiler error at all, but an error owing to some files in the project setup.  [Better SBT documentation may be found here.](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/index.html)

It's absolutely true that SBT isn't needed for very simple examples, and indeed offends the sensibilities of ones volunteering to learn a new language (soon to be improved, [Scala 3.x](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2018/04/19/scala-3.html), not a hundred other extraneous technologies.  I find IntelliJ Idea Community to be a boost, here, since its Scala support is first-rate, and will create simple example projects for you in a variety of ways [Installing Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/intellij-track/getting-started-with-scala-in-intellij.html) / [Installing Scala plugin for Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/discover-intellij-idea-for-scala.html#scala_plugin).